# How to return a list called in a class in python

Tags: python, list, object

Struggling with this:

> Write a function called get_pets_string. get_pets_string should
> have one parameter, an instance of Owner. get_pets_string
> should return a list of that owner's pets according to the
> following format:
>
> ```
> David Joyner's pets are: Boggle Joyner, Artemis Joyner
> ```

```py
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
```

> If your function works correctly, this will originally
> print:
>
> ```
> David Joyner's pets are: Boggle Joyner, Artemis Joyner
> Audrey Hepburn's pets are: Pippin Hepburn
> ```

```py
owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))

pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)

owner_1.pets.append(pet_1)
owner_1.pets.append(pet_2)
owner_2.pets.append(pet_3)

print(get_pets_string(owner_1))
print(get_pets_string(owner_2))
```

Here is my code as below:

```py
def get_pets_string(owner):
    for obj in owner.pets:
       return owner.name.first + " " + owner.name.last + "'s pets are: " + obj.name.first + " " + obj.name.last
```

My answer can only print one pet for each owner like this:

```py
David Joyner's pets are: Boggle Joyner
Audrey Hepburn's pets are: Pippin Hepburn
```

Comment: In your `get_pets_string` function, you are returning only one pet because, once the function reach the return statement, it returns what it has at that point and ends. So, you only get one iteration in the for loop. Why don't you try to create the list of pet names first and then, once you have all the pets in the list, just return it!

Comment: First, you are printing the owner's name in front of every pet. Second, you are using `return` inside your `for` loop, which causes the function to immediately return. You need to accumulate the results.

Comment: As an aside, this is a really crappy OOP homework assignment....

Comment: Just to explain ddejohn comment: the classes they're giving you are just complicated ways of writing dictionaries. Instead of `owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))`, it would be a better practice just to do `owner_1 =  {'first_name' : 'David', 'last_name': 'Joyner'}`. It's "crappy" not just because it doesn't exploit properly the power of objects (which could make sense if it's just introducing a concept), but also because it teaches poor practices (not using the proper tool, a dictionary in this case.).

Comment: @ Ignatius Reilly: Thank you for your explanation! I just started to learn Python for one month. This is a question from online course GTx CS1301xIV from Georgia Tech on Edx. I just started to learn the definition of objects. This problem is for the section "objects", I guess to use `owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner")) ` instead of format of dictionary is because to match the content of section "objects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a quick helper function to change how the string is displayed and simply displaying the name:

```py
def repr_name(name):
    return name.first + " " + name.last
```

Then you can display all the pets together:

```py
def get_pets_string(owner):
   return f"{repr_name(owner.name)}'s pets are: {', '.join([repr_name(pet.name) for pet in owner.pets])}"
```

The `', '.join([str(pet.name) for pet in owner.pets])` puts the name of every pet into the list, and then separates each of them with commas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the problem cannot revise or add codes to the codes provided in the problem. The three classes Name, Pet and Owner cannot be revised and added.

Comment: @BonnieZou Edited. That's not really a big problem, it can be added by itself (and it's really just to feed my laziness).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` on a generator expression that yields formatted strings.

```
', '.join(f"{pet.name.first} {pet.name.first}" for pet in owner_1.pets)
```

This yields:

```
'Boggle Boggle, Artemis Artemis'
```

As this is homework, I don't want to give you the whole solution, so I'll leave it to you to put this piece together with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you're returning immediately in your first iteration

```
def get_pets_string(owner):
    for obj in owner.pets:
       return owner.name.first + " " + owner.name.last + "'s pets are: " + obj.name.first + " " + obj.name.last
        #^ here is the problem, you need to iterate over your whole list but this stop after the first iteration
```

You need to construct your result cumulatively, like so

```
def get_pets_string(owner):
    owner_name = owner.name.first + " " + owner.name.last + "'s pets are: "
    pets = []
    for obj in owner.pets:
       pets.append(obj.name.first + " " + obj.name.last) #gather all the pets names in a list
    return  owner_name + ", ".join(pets) #use join to put together all the pets name we build previously
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your function is returning the value. Return implies the end of the function, so its not iterating through the other pets.

The function should be like the follow...

```py
def get_pets_string(owner):
    owner_string = f"{owner.name.first} {owner.name.last}'s pets are: "
    
    pets_string = ""
    for obj in owner.pets:
        pet_name = f"{obj.name.first} {obj.name.last}"
        pets_string += pet_name + " "
    
    return owner_string + pets_string
```

---

You can actually refactor your code by returning fullname as methon on each class